# In flutter, how to use Semantic on SliverPersistentHeader?

Tags: flutter

- I Want to make SliverPersistentHeader as a semantics.

> SliverPersistentHeader is a horizontal list

- some error info

> FlutterError (A RenderViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderSemanticsAnnotations.

---

Here is source example which I would rewrite:
https://github.com/rydmike/flex_color_scheme/blob/master/example/lib/example5/widgets/pages/large_grid_view.dart#L164

> playground https://rydmike.com/flexcolorscheme/themesplayground-v5

---

Answer (score 0):

- Although you may not use Semantics directly in CustomScrollView, but found that SliverPersistentHeader is a fixed height, we also found that SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate build What is returned is a Widget.
- You can add Semantics to
  https://github.com/rydmike/flex_color_scheme/blob/master/example/lib/example5/widgets/panels/theme_selector.dart#L114